# Using 30" cinema display as TV

Tags: displayport, television, cinema-display

I have the old (now discontinued) [30" cinema display](http://www.everymac.com/monitors/apple/studio_cinema/specs/apple_cinema_display_30.html), but I don't use it that much anymore so I'm thinking of converting it to a TV if possible.

Yes I could get a TV tuner but I'm not sure about the cables, how would it connect with TV tuners? I already have **Mini-DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI** cable, is there any TV tuner available that supports it?

Comment: Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a DisplayPort-based external TV tuner.

But there are HDMI-based TV tuners available, and HDMI-DVI adapters are cheap.

Single-link DVI supports 1920x1200 at 60 Hz, which is higher than any digital broadcast TV standard, so that wouldn't be your limiting factor.